# Flutter web download file working locally but not in production

Tags: flutter, dart

On my website you can download a PDF of my resume by clicking a button. The PDF is located in the assets folder inside my project. When I test on local the download works perfectly, but once deployed it says 'Failed - No file'.

download function

```
downloadFile(url) {
    AnchorElement anchorElement = AnchorElement(
      href: url,
    );
    anchorElement.download = "resume.pdf";
    anchorElement.click();
}
```

download button

```
TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: () {
            downloadFile("assets/resume.pdf");
          },
          style: ButtonStyle(
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 15, 30, 15)),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    side: const BorderSide(
                        color: MyColors.lightBlue, width: 2))),
          ),
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.sim_card_download_outlined,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 20,
          ),
          label: Text(
            ResponsiveWrapper.of(context).isDesktop
                ? 'DOWNLOAD FULL RESUME'
                : 'RESUME',
            style: MyFonts.roundedMedium,
          ),
        ),
```

pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
  - assets/placeholder.jpg
  - assets/profilePic.jpg
  - assets/resume.pdf
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of just asking for Permission.storage  i added two more permission requests Permission.accessMediaLocation , Permission.manageExternalStorage in order to support all versions of Android.

```
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage) &&
      await _requestPermission(Permission.accessMediaLocation) &&
      await _requestPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage)) {

-----do your work here 

}
```

Comment: My project is running on flutter web only